# GraphServiceClient not working with Microsoft Identity Web in Razor Page model

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, razor-pages, microsoft-identity-web

I have a situation where I can successfully use GraphServiceClient in my Startup but not in my Razor Page. I am using Microsoft Identity Web with Microsoft Graph and have followed the MS Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-call-api?tabs=aspnetcore) and also checked many other similar issues but I always end up with the same error...

> MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the
> AcquireTokenSilent call

Note that my app registration is in my tenant but user account in customer tenant. Therefore my app authentication is configured with "Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)" and the below API Permissions...

[image]

My settings is below and although it's a multi-tenant app I only have one customer and therefore setting the TenantId to my customer tenant id for a streamlined login experience.

```
"AzureAd": {
"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
"TenantId": "<Customer Tenant Id>",
"ClientId": "<My App Reg Id>",
"ClientSecret": "<My App Reg Secret>",
"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
},
"DownstreamApi": {
"BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
"Scopes": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
}
```

My Startup has the following ConfigureServices method. Note that the call to graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync() works here and returns the user info from my customer Azure AD. I plan to use this to populate my local database with extra user info (ie photo) when the user logs in to my app.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
        });
        services.AddRazorPages()
            .AddMvcOptions(options => { })
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

        var initialScopes = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(',');
        services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
            .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

        services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerValidator = ValidateSpecificIssuers; //restrict access for multi-tenant app
            options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {
                OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                {
                    GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async request =>
                    {
                        // Add the access token in the Authorization header of the API request.
                        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.TokenEndpointResponse.AccessToken);
                    }));

                    try
                    {
                        var user = await graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync(); // THIS CALL WORKS!
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Cannot get user info from AAD");
                    }

                    await Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            };
        });


    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }

    private string ValidateSpecificIssuers(string issuer, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
    {
        var validIssuers = Configuration["AllowedIssuers"];
        if (validIssuers != null && validIssuers.Split(',').Select(tid => $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tid}").Contains(issuer))
        {
            return issuer;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException("The user account does not belong to an allowed tenant");
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my Razor Page however it always fails on the same graph call even though it works in my Startup file. I have tried changing the scope from "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0" to "user.read" everywhere but it still fails at this line.

> var user = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();

```
[AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" })]
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
    private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
    }

    public async void OnGet()
    {
        try
        {
            var user = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync(); // THIS CALL FAILS!
            using (var photoStream = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Photo.Content.Request().GetAsync())
            {
                byte[] photoByte = ((MemoryStream)photoStream).ToArray();
                ViewData["photo"] = Convert.ToBase64String(photoByte);
            }
            ViewData["name"] = user.DisplayName;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the stack trace of the error.

```
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Code: generalException
Message: An error occurred sending the request.

  Source=Microsoft.Graph.Core
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendRequestAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.<SendAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendRequestAsync>d__40.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendAsync>d__34`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Graph.UserRequest.<GetAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Test365.Pages.IndexModel.<OnGet>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\Users\ojmcf\source\repos\Test365\Pages\Index.cshtml.cs:line 28

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
MicrosoftIdentityWebChallengeUserException: IDW10502: An MsalUiRequiredException was thrown due to a challenge for the user. See https://aka.ms/ms-id-web/ca_incremental-consent. 

Inner Exception 2:
MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call.
```

Comment: Can you show me your sample code in Startup.cs  without any sensitive info ?

Comment: @JasonPan updated question with full Startup file minus includes

Comment: Tks, I will check it.

Answer (score 2):

Simple fix in the end. I had assumed Razor Pages was handling the authorization globally as setup in Startup file so I overlooked the `[Authorize]` attribute at the top of the Page Model. Once I added that it started working as expected.

However for convenience I ended up removing the `[Authorize]` attribute from Page Model and instead added it globally using `RequireAuthorization()` under endpoint routing in Configure method of Startup file.

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages().RequireAuthorization();
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
```

Comment: I have since retested and above solution did not work. It did initially but after restarting app on my localhost the same error persists

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Try to add `/v2.0` in your url like below.

```
validIssuers.Split(',').Select(tid => $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tid}/v2.0").Contains(issuer)
```

Replace the following code

```
[AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0" })]
```

with

```
[AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new[] { "user.read" })]
```

, and test it.

***Tips***

This url(`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0`) should be in `appsettings.json` file.

Comment: I did try that already as mentioned but I did it again anyway and still same error

Comment: @OjM Try to use `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`, not `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0`.

Comment: sorry I missed that. I updated to correct scope `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` but still same error. I've also updated the question with the correct scope at top of page model

Comment: @OjM Can you share me the sample email address ? Can you use email which format like  `XXX@custom.onmicrosoft.com` ?

Comment: The ValidateSpecificIssuers method is already working as expected with my setting `"AllowedIssuers": "<my tenant id>/v2.0,<customer tenant id>/v2.0"`. Not sure what you mean by using/sharing email address?

Comment: @OjM Try to use work accounts, not personal account.

Comment: I'm not using personal account. I'm only using a test work account provided by my customer. The account authenticates fine and logs in ok but just fails with the graph request in the Page Model. Note the error is the same regardless of whether I set the TenantId to "organizations" or "<Customer Tenant Id>" in my appsettings file.

Comment: Any luck with a solution? Same thing is happening for me.

Comment: @brsfan you can post your question with correct tag, then the community who familiar with the issue will help you